# Asymmetric encryption in SSH

Tags: ssh, diffie-hellman

I read [this article](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-the-ssh-encryption-and-connection-process) about the SSH protocol, and there's something I don't quite understand.  The author explains that basically all the communication during the session is encrypted using symmetric encryption, i.e. both sides establish a shared secret (Using an appropriate algorithm such as diffie-hellman). All this takes place prior to the authentication stage.

For authentication, different methods can be used. One of them is public-key authentication, meaning that the server holds a list of  public keys in a `authorized_keys` file (in the user's .ssh directory), and clients that hold the corresponding private keys are authorized to log in. So this asymmetric encryption is only used for authentication. Once the client is authenticated, we're done with that and the rest of the session is still encrypted with the shared secret.

What I don't understand is this paragraph from the article:

> SSH utilizes asymmetric encryption in a few different places. During the initial key exchange process used to set up the symmetrical encryption (used to encrypt the session), asymmetrical encryption is used. In this stage, both parties produce temporary key pairs and exchange the public key in order to produce the shared secret that will be used for symmetrical encryption.

What is this procedure of "both parties produce temporary key pairs and exchange etc." ? Does this refer to the procedure I described above i.e. using the diffie-hellman algorithm to produce the shared secret? Or is that something else? if is, what is it and why is it needed?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, ephemeral Diffie-Hellman (which is what's used here) involves both sides generating temporary key pairs and exchanging them to create a shared secret.  This can be done using finite-field (integer) DH (the `diffie-hellman-*` algorithms) or the elliptic curve variant (`ecdh-*` and `curve*`).  Both are secure with sufficient key sizes.

The reason this is necessary is that the client and server don't have any other way to generate encryption keys.  In fact, they may not have even connected before.  Using Diffie-Hellman to negotiate a shared secret that attackers don't know allows them to securely derive a set of keys that only they know.  Furthermore, if they discard all the key material after they're done, the connection has what we call *perfect forward secrecy*; that is, nobody can recover the data faster than brute force, even if compelled.

Comment: What's confusing here is that, as far as I understand, diffie-hellman algorithm doesn't really include "generating key pairs and exchanging public keys". I mean it's not an asymmetric encryption scheme the same way RSA is. Am I right?

Comment: Correct, it's not an asymmetric encryption scheme, not is it an asymmetric signature scheme.  It's an asymmetric key-agreement scheme.